# ElastAlert: Using wildcards in blacklist to match subdomains

Tags: elasticsearch, blacklist, elastalert

So I am trying to set up a blacklist in ElastAlert but are struggling with the wildcard matching.

The end goal is for me to have an a file that I populate with domains. 
The ElastAlert rule then reads this blacklist file and alerts me if any of the domains, including subdomains, has been hit.

So far I got it to work with exact matches against the domain listed in the file. (i.e. `evil-domain.com`)
However, I have not been able to match a subdomain in the same way such as `www.evil-domain.com`

I have tried with many different wildcard matches in the file such as:

- `*evil-domain.com/`
- `.+evil-domian.com/`
- `/*evil-domain.com/`

But none of them work, or at least I havent managed to get them working. 

Is such usecase possbile in ElastAlert, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The code does not currently support it.

I made a commit to add regex support:

https://github.com/johnflux/elastalert-1